# no data binding between directive's scope and it's template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive which contains this input element in it's html template:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" ng-model="searchValue" ng-keyup="keyup($event, searchValue)">
```

Here is the directive js file:

```
define(['angular', 'module'], function (angular, module) {
    'use strict';

    var templateUrl = module.uri.replace('.js', '.html');

    angular.module('App.directives')
        .directive('navBar',[function() {
            return {
                scope: {
                    options: '=options'
                },  
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: 'true',
                templateUrl: templateUrl,
                link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
                    $scope.$watch('options', function (val) {
                        var options = $scope.options || {};

                        if(options.search) {
                            $scope.searchValue = options.search.initValue || '';

                            $scope.keyup = function(e, value) {
                                options.search.onSearch(e, value);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }]);
});
```

My problem is that the controller not renders the model values on the view.

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8d5fj8Lo/1/).

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking here... Are you expecting to see that $scope.message rendered somewhere?

Comment: @coma, see the `blarg` value of scope (line 21) it is not changing the view (search for `{{blarg}}` in the template).

Comment: Ah, ok, you are talking about the link function...

Comment: @coma, so can you point out the problem?

Comment: did you just forked a jsfiddle from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/Ovn-5jVK3So (2012!), it is using Angular 1.0.0.

Comment: Nope, I just googled for jsfiddle directive example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure if this is what your are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/8d5fj8Lo/2/

```
app.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" ng-model="searchValue"><span>{{blarg}}, {{searchValue}}</span></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {

            $scope.$watch('searchValue', function (n, o) {

                if (n === o) {

                    return;
                }

                $scope.blarg = n + 'fooo';
            });
        }
    };
});
```

So basically, instead of listening the keyup event and passing to the listener the searchValue, just watch it.

I removed the $watched on the options since it was doing nothing there.

Comment: why do I need to use watch? why there is no 2 way data binding between the scope and the view?

Comment: more over I need to know which key was pressed and for that I need the event.

Comment: Here I updated you fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8d5fj8Lo/5/ and it is working. Can you explain why? More over I do need to watch the options object which is passed to the directive

Comment: Your initial jsfiddle is using 1.0.0 and I'm sure there is an issue on using the ng-keyup there, compare http://jsfiddle.net/coma/8d5fj8Lo/4/ to http://jsfiddle.net/coma/8d5fj8Lo/6/ , the first one is using 1.2.

Comment: At my project I am using 1.3, and while debugging I am getting inside the keyup function but searchValue is always an empty string

Comment: Thanks!  Maybe u can do the angular version update on the original fiddle and see the problem there